# In Perl, why do I get "undefined subroutine" in a perl module but not in main ?

Tags: perl

I'm getting an "undefined subroutine" for sub2 in the code below but not for sub1.

This is the perl script (try.pl)...

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use IO::CaptureOutput qw(capture_exec_combined);

use FindBin qw($Bin);
use lib "$Bin";
use try_common;

print "Running try.pl\n";
sub1("echo \"in sub1\"");
sub2("echo \"in sub2\"");

exit;

sub sub1 {

(my $cmd) = @_;

print "Executing... \"${cmd}\"\n";
my ($stdouterr, $success, $exit_code) = capture_exec_combined($cmd);
print "${stdouterr}\n";

return;
}
```

This is try_common.pm...

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use IO::CaptureOutput qw(capture_exec_combined);

package try_common;

use Exporter;
our @ISA = qw(Exporter);
our @EXPORT = qw(
  sub2
);

sub sub2 {

    (my $cmd) = @_;

    print "Executing... \"${cmd}\"\n";
    my ($stdouterr, $success, $exit_code) = capture_exec_combined($cmd);
    print "${stdouterr}\n";

    return;
}

1;
```

When I run try.pl I get...

```
% ./try.pl
Running try.pl
Executing... "echo "in sub1""
in sub1

Executing... "echo "in sub2""
Undefined subroutine &try_common::capture_exec_combined called at 
/home/me/PERL/try_common.pm line 20.
```

This looks like some kind of scoping issue because if I cut/paste the "use IO::CaptureOutput qw(capture_exec_combined);" as the first line of sub2, it works.  This is not necessary in the try.pl (it runs sub1 OK), but a problem in the perl module.   Hmmmm....

Thanks in Advance for any help!

Comment: It makes no sense to add a shebang (`#!`) line to a .pm file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You imported `capture_exec_combined` by the `use` clause before declaring the package, so it was imported into the `main` package, not the `try_common`. Move the package declaration further up.

Comment: Hmmmm...  So one way to get everything into the main space would be to omit the "package" statement altogether ?   I have 2 different main scripts that are going to use the stuff in this perl module.  I'm beginning to wonder what the point is in using the "package" statement at all.

Comment: Omitting the `package` statement would cause more troubles in the long run than it would solve. Learn to write proper Perl modules (see [perlmod](http://p3rl.org/perlmod)).

Comment: @daveg, For the same reason as you are using multiple files: For separation of unrelated things. This separation allows modules to have subs with the same name, for example. There's no way you can guarantee that your module won't have the same as any other module your program might use. /// It also allows the program to have more than one class.

Comment: @ikegami … which can make them more _classy_ ;-)

Comment: @PerlDuck, You're so y.

Comment: @ikegami Errr … thank you. They force you to write that, right?

Answer (score 4):

You should take a look at the [perlmod](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html) document to understand how modules work. In short:

1. When you use `package A` (in Perl 5), you change the namespace of the following code to `A`, and all global symbol (e.g. subroutine) definitions after that point will go into that package. Subroutines inside a scope need not be *exported* and may be used preceded by their scope name: `A::function`. This you seem to have found.
2. Perl uses `package` as a way to create *modules* and split code in different files, but also as the basis for its object orientation features.
3. Most of the times, *modules* are handled by a special core module called `Exporter`. See [Exporter](http://perldoc.perl.org/Exporter.html). This module uses some variables to know what to do, like `@EXPORT`, `@EXPORT_OK` or `@ISA`. The first defines the names that should be exported by default when you *include* the module with `use Module`. The second defines the names that may be exported (but need to be mentioned with `use Module qw(name1 name2)`. The last tells in an object oriented fashion what your module *is*. If you don't care about object orientation, your module typically "is a" `Exporter`.

Also, as stated in another answer, when you define a module, the `package module` declaration should be the first thing to be in the file so anything after it will be under that scope.

Comment: Thanks you for this detailed explanation.  I'm cutting and pasting it into my notes now :-)

Comment: Sure, have a look at the links too. This is only a brief summary.

Answer (score 0):

I hate when I make this mistake although I don't make it much anymore. There are two habits you can develop:

Most likely, make the entire file the package. The first lines will be the `package` statement and no other `package` statements show up in the file.

Or, use the new PACKAGE BLOCK syntax and put everything for that package inside the block. I do this for small classes that I might need only locally:

```
package Foo {
    # everything including use statements go in this block
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I think I figured it out.  If, in the perl module, I prefix the "capture_exec_combined" with "::", it works.

Still, why isn't this needed in the main, try.pl ?

Comment: This should be in comment not an answer